# Should Java Applets include HTML in the byte count?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

I'm curious whether or not the HTML required to run applets should be included in byte count. Also what's the current standard for counting bytes with applets? In Eclipse if I recall correctly you can run applets without HTML, however in other IDE's you need the HTML.

Comment: Definitely a good question. I think IntelliJ also lets you forgo the html file as does appletviewer (although that might need a laxed security manager).

Comment: @Poke Aye, though if you use AppletViewer you can still run the applet in any situation, while without the HTML you can only run it in certain IDEs/situations.

Comment: For browser JavaScript we don't count the <script> tag so I don't believe so here. However I am not too familiar with Java applets to provide an answer

Answer (score 7):

#### We define languages by their implementation here.

So as long as there is an IDE or whatever other interpreter that runs your applet without wrapping it in HTML, you are totally fine.
Of course you have to specify in  your submission which setup your code requires to be run successfully.